# react font-awesome icon is not showing in css content

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use fontawesome in React in css content and getting blank square instead of the icon. When using normally with html tag, it's working properly.

I installed the npm react-fontawesome and also pasted the cdn in my public index.html. I do prefer to use it in the old way (such as with pure js) and the normal html tags are working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

css:

```
  .answer-selected::before {
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: '\f00c'
  }
```

Same icon is working as a html tag:

```
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess font awesome class name is `fa` not `fas`

Comment: check this once it's working perfectly https://codesandbox.io/s/10ozmnk1oj

Comment: try font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"

Comment: Thanks a lot, "Font Awesome 5 Free" fixed it